# Join mySQL query and only return certain results?

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have two queries:

```
$iQ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE `released` > '" . $begin . 
    "' AND `released` < '" . $end . "' ORDER BY `views` DESC LIMIT 5");

while ($iR = mysql_fetch_array($iQ)) {
    $imageQ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `movie_image`
        WHERE `movie_id` = '" . $iR['id'] . "' AND `image_size` = 'thumb'
        AND `type` = 'poster' LIMIT 1");
}
```

I want to put this in to one query, and I only want to return results IF there are rows in the movie_image table, meaning movies without images won't be returned in the result set.

How can I go about joining these two queries, so I can get the movie image with the first query, and only return the result if there IS a movie image present for the movie ID?

Let me know if you don't understand and I'll try rephrase my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `movies`
    INNER JOIN `movie_image` ON `movie_image`.`movie_id` = `movies`.`id`
    WHERE `movies`.`released` > '" . $begin . "'
    AND `movies`.`released` < '" . $end . "'
    AND `movie_image`.`image_size` = 'thumb'
    AND `type` = 'poster' ORDER BY `movies`.`views` DESC LIMIT 5
```

This query should work for you.

Comment: This is bringing back 2 of the same result, everything has the same image.

Comment: I'm guessing you have multiple images per movie?

Comment: Yes there are multiple images per movie, and I also need info from the `movies` table too.

Answer (score 0):

First thing the relation here is a one-many relationship so you cannot do it in one query.

Second, to return the movies if there is a movie image present you need to check that in the first query, then iterate through the first query to get the images related to each movie.

```
$iq = "SELECT m.* FROM `movies` m 
      RIGHT JOIN `movie_images` mi ON mi.movie_id = m.movie_id
      WHERE `m.released` > '" 
      . $begin . "' AND `m.released` < '" . $end . "' GROUP BY `m.movie_id` ORDER BY `m.views` 
      DESC LIMIT 5";

$res = mysql_query($iq);
while($ir = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
  //get the images for each movie here
}
```

Comment: What do you get with the first query? You should get all the movies that have at least one image in `movie_images`

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this query helps you. If movies table identifier = id(ms.id).

```
SELECT mi.* FROM movie_image mi
    JOIN movies ms ON mi.movie_id = ms.id
    WHERE ms.released > '" . $begin . "'
    AND ms.released < '" . $end . "'
    AND mi.image_size = 'thumb' AND mi.type = 'poster'
    ORDER BY ms.views DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select one of the matching images, but don't care which (that's what your current query does), you can just join the tables and `GROUP BY` movie id (I assume that it's `UNIQUE` in `movies`, e.g. the primary key):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     movies
    JOIN movie_image 
      ON movie_image.movie_id = movies.id
     AND movie_image.image_size = 'thumb'
     AND movie_image.type = 'poster'
WHERE    movies.released BETWEEN :begin AND :end
GROUP BY movies.id
ORDER BY views DESC
LIMIT    5
```